# upload and display image on browser

Tags: php, image, post, upload

Does anyone know how I can make a user interface where the person uploads an image and the image is displayed on the screen?
Sort of like facebook or flickr uploads or something.

Comment: What platforms are you using on the client and server side?

Comment: I'm a total newbie on this. i'm using firefox browser. php or js will do i suppose....

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax or/and flash.

For instance [here](http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload) and [here](http://atwebresults.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=391) are used ajax.

Another flash example [here](http://demo.lionite.com/js/tiny_mce/plugins/lioniteimages/lioniteimages.htm) but it is paid service.